# How to prove if an arithmetic function is multiplicative?

Tags: prime-numbers, multiplicative-function

I know that for an arithmetic function to be multiplicative then $f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$ for $(n,m)=1$

I have just proved that:

$$f(n) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{if 10|n}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if 10 doesn't divide n}
  \end{array} \right.$$

isn't multiplicative. I just want to firstly check that I did this correctly.
I chose $n=2$ and $m=5$
so $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$?

$f(2 \cdot 5) = f(2)f(5)$

$f(10)=f(2)f(5)$

$0 \neq 1$ $\quad$ $\Box$

I am now trying to prove that

$$g(n) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{if 9|n}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if 9 doesn't divide n}
  \end{array} \right.$$

is multiplicative.

How do I prove this for every $n$ and $m$?

Any guidance would be great! Thank you

Comment: Could you do it if $9$ were $3$?

Comment: @Hurkyl : I tried something in case of $3$... i take $m,n$ are coprimes so... $m,n$ are $3k,3k+1$ or $3k+1,3k+2$... I do not want to say anything on $3k,3k+2$ as they may not be co prime always... $0=f((3k)\cdot (3k+1))=f(3k)\cdot f(3k+1)=0\cdot 1=0 $ and $1=f((3k+1)\cdot (3k+2))=f(3k+1)\cdot f(3k+2)=1\cdot 1=1$... I have no idea what would be the case of  $3k, 3k+2$ :O

Comment: @Hurkyl : please have a look at my comment

Comment: Do you mean [multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), or [completely multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function)? You've given the definition of a completely multiplicative function, but the result you're trying to prove isn't true if you require complete multiplicativity.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. Then at most one of $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $3$.

If neither is divisible by $3$, then $ab$ isn't divisible by $3$, and $f(a)f(b)=1 \cdot 1 = f(ab)$.

If one of them is divisible by $3$, without loss of generality, let it be $a$ that's divisible by $3$.
If $a$ is not divisible by $9$, then $ab$ isn't divisible by $9$, and $f(a)f(b) = 1 \cdot 1 = f(ab)$.
Otherwise, $a$ and $ab$ are divisible by $9$, and $f(a)f(b) = 0 \cdot 1 = f(ab)$.